# A question about penalty regression

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

why

$min_{\beta} \|X\beta-y\|^2+\lambda\|\beta\|_\ell$

is equivalent to

$min_\beta \|X\beta-y\|^2$

$s.t.$

$\|\beta\|_\ell<t$

Comment: You should add more context.

Comment: Lagrange duality / Lagrange multipliers